# how to calulate the column cells in gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

i have grid view with column ..price ...

```
Sno.        Product            price ($)
1           Pencil             1
2           Rubber             3
3           sharpner           2
```

I want to calulate the price column .... means //// i want to calculate the cells in Price column of GridView .....

the reult of price will be shown as 1+3+2 = 6

Comment: how is your gridview bound? autogeneratecolumns. templatefields or bound fields? where do you want the sum appear at (footer or another control) ?

Comment: Boud field ...normally .... bounded to sqldatasource1

Answer (score 0):

You could use Datatable's [compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) function to calculate the sum:

```
    Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
            e.Row.Cells(2).Text = DirectCast(Me.GridView1.DataSource, DataTable).Compute("SUM(Price)", Nothing).ToString
        End If
    End Sub
```

This was my Testdata:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            BindFooData()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindFooData()
        Dim tblFoo As New DataTable("Foo")
        tblFoo.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ID", GetType(Int32)))
        tblFoo.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Product", GetType(String)))
        tblFoo.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Price", GetType(Double)))
        Dim drProduct As DataRow = tblFoo.NewRow
        drProduct("ID") = 1
        drProduct("Product") = "Pencil"
        drProduct("Price") = 1
        tblFoo.Rows.Add(drProduct)
        drProduct = tblFoo.NewRow
        drProduct("ID") = 2
        drProduct("Product") = "Rubber"
        drProduct("Price") = 3
        tblFoo.Rows.Add(drProduct)
        drProduct = tblFoo.NewRow
        drProduct("ID") = 3
        drProduct("Product") = "sharpner"
        drProduct("Price") = 2
        tblFoo.Rows.Add(drProduct)
        Me.GridView1.DataSource = tblFoo
        Me.GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        Me.GridView1.ShowFooter = True
        Me.GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

Or you could calculate it manually:

```
       Private AllPrices As New List(Of Double)

       Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
            If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                Dim price As Double = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)("Price"), Double)
                AllPrices.Add(price)
            ElseIf e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
                Dim TotalPrice As Double
                Dim TotalUnitPriceText As New System.Text.StringBuilder
                For Each price As Double In AllPrices
                    TotalPrice += price
                    TotalUnitPriceText.Append(price).Append("+")
                Next
                If TotalUnitPriceText.Length <> 0 Then
                    TotalUnitPriceText.Length -= 1
                    TotalUnitPriceText.Append(" = ")
                End If
                e.Row.Cells(1).Text = TotalUnitPriceText.ToString
                e.Row.Cells(2).Text = TotalPrice.ToString
            End If
        End Sub
```

---

Last but not least you could calculate it with your sql-query with [SUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx).